# Realm queries are returning dictionaries instead of objects

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, realm

Here is the `Course` object I want to store using Realm :

```
class Course: Object {

    var name: String = ""
    var code: String = ""
    var CRN: Int = 0
    var capacity: Int = 0
    var occupied: Int = 0

    required init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
        super.init(realm: realm, schema: schema)
    }

    required init(value: Any, schema: RLMSchema) {
        super.init(value: value, schema: schema)
    }

}
```

Here's how I am writing the object to the Realm :

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        try! self.realm.write {
        self.realm.add(course)
    }
}
```

Here's how I  am reading the object :

```
for course in realm.objects(Course.self) {
    self.courses.append(course)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I am using a `configure` function to set up a `UITableViewCell` with a `Course` object :

```
func configure(withCourse course: Course) {

    self.codeLabel.text = course.name
    self.nameLabel.text = course.code
}
```

However, this does nothing.

This is what I have to do to use to get the `UITableViewCell` to configure correctly :

```
self.codeLabel.text = course.value(forKeyPath: "name") as! String?
self.nameLabel.text = course.value(forKeyPath: "code") as! String?
```

How do I access its properties, and not values in a dictionary ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The properties in your model class are missing the `dynamic` modifier. This modifier is necessary to ensure that Realm has an opportunity to intercept access to the properties, giving Realm an opportunity to read / write the data from the file on disk. Omitting these properties results in the Swift compiler accessing the instance variables directly, cutting Realm out of the loop. Your model class should look more like:

```
class Course: Object {
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    dynamic var code: String = ""
    dynamic var CRN: Int = 0
    dynamic var capacity: Int = 0
    dynamic var occupied: Int = 0
}
```

None of the various `init` methods included in your code snippet appear to be necessary either.